# how do I convert textbox value to string?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I know this is simple but i am lost as to how to approach it. Iam a new newbie. Please have it on me as i am new here.

I have a textbox field called ClientsBalance.

This balance can is usually in money order with a set amount. The client is also allowed to pay by Debit Cards.

Here goes:

```
Dim paymentType As TextBox
otherPyment As String = "Debit Card"

If paymentType.Text <> "1250" Then
  paymentType = "OtherPayment"
else
   paymentType = gridview1.FindControl("paymentType" & CStr(1))
end if
```

Everything was working before the validation.

Now, I get the following error:

Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox'

Is there a way I can cast this line:

paymentType = "OtherPayment"
??

Thank you so much experts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to say

`paymentType.Text = "OtherPayment"`.

You just left out the ".Text"

Comment: Note: you'll need to fix both lines where you set PaymentType actually.

Comment: Are you sure? `gridview1.FindControl("paymentType" & CStr(1))` will return a control that can be assigned directly to paymentType

Comment: I'm not sure now that you mention it. I should have said he 'may' need to fix both lines because I noticed that it was set after the else as well.  Good catch.  It might work as coded.

Comment: @ChidiOkeh Don't forget to mark nycdan's answer as the accepted answer if you are satisfied with his response. Many of us here aren't experts, we're just regular guys like you. Welcome to SO :)

Comment: thank you experts. I just accepted his answer. Also, I don't understand comments by Kiley Naro about fixing both lines. Can you please explain?

Comment: actually, it looks like you accepted another answer instead.  It's okay, but you should generally accept the first one if they are saying the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing this:

```
paymentType = "OtherPayment"
```

To this:

```
paymentType.Text = "OtherPayment"
```